# Missing glyphs in OhMyPosh and Caskaydia Cove

Tags: windows-terminal, oh-my-posh

So I have a OhMyPosh theme and the latest Caskaydia Cove Mono Regular (just downlonaded [from GitHub](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/blob/master/patched-fonts/CascadiaCode/Regular/CaskaydiaCoveNerdFontMono-Regular.ttf)) and the git glyph is not showing prope[image: cli]

I use Windows Terminal and PowerShell 7. Here are settings:
[image: windows terminal settings]

This issue exists for every Posh Theme.

Comment: hardly a `git` question

Comment: true, edited tags

Comment: Does the problem consist in other nerd fonts?
Does the problem consist with `CascadyCove Nerd Font` (not Mono?)
The current version of Windows Terminal is `1.18.`
Glyph Display improved in the last two version `1.17` and `1.18`

Answer (score 0):

There are breaking changes with Nerd Fonts 3.0. See the [release notes](https://www.nerdfonts.com/releases) for specifics.

The main culprit is most likely that **Material Design Icons** were moved to a new codepoint.

What you can do to fix:

- Search for any existing **icons** in your json file [here](https://www.nerdfonts.com/cheat-sheet).
- If it comes up with a "Removed" response - you have found the problem.
- You can search for a similar icon and use that instead.

Alternatively, there is a full lookup table and some scripts [here](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/issues/1059#issuecomment-1404891287).